# UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile does not work (ImageNamed works fine)

Tags: ios7, uiimage, xcode5

I am struggling to display image.

The following codes work fine.

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture"];
```

or

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture.png"];
```

But the following codes do not work.

```
NSString *theImagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"picture" ofType:@"png"];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:theImagePath];
```

or

```
imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"picture" ofType:@"png"]];
```

I tried clean up the project but it has not fixed yet.
Does anyone have same experience?

Comment: Theres no reason it shouldn't be working. The error is most likely somewhere else inside of your code. Also, why do you not want to use `imageNamed`?

Comment: Have you tried breaking down some of those calls?  In the case of using NSString *theImagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"picture" ofType:@"png"]; does theImagePath return anything?

Comment: @PeterFoti Because I got memory warning and found imageNamed makes memory warning if big image is shown or imageNamed called many times.

Comment: @RobSegal theImagePath return (null). Any ideas?

Comment: @tomo ok well that is definitely revealing.  Did you try NSString *theImagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"picture.png" ofType:@""]?  You should also examining the packaged binary to make sure your image is really in the bundle to be found.

Comment: @RobSegal thanks. yes, I tried and theImagePath returns (null). I can see images.xcassets in Build Phases->Copy Bundle Resources. Huh...

Comment: @tomo good that it is in the Copy Bundle Resources phase but don't rely on Xcode fully.  Find the .app binary it produces in finder, open it up and see that the image is part of the binary.

Answer (score -1):

`imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"picture.png" ofType:nil]];`

Give it a shot, probably Xcode does not recognize your file as a PNG file.

But why don't you stay with `imageNamed:`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As you suggest, I tried but it's same result.